# In Xcode target Build Phases, what is the difference between 'Compile Sources' and 'Copy Bundle Resources'?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am adding a Core Data model file to my project along with a static library that uses it, however I am not sure whether to put it in the 'Compile Sources' phase or the 'Copy Bundle Resources' phase. What is the difference between the two?

Comment: The former is for items to be compiled/processed during the building of the target. The latter is for assets not to be processed, but merely to be included in the final app (e.g. images). If you create new project that uses CoreData, it includes the `xcdatamodeld` file under "Compile Sources".

Comment: @Rob That explanation makes a lot of sense, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically the "*Compile Sources*" phase complies your source code files, that means that takes all your source files and compile them into [object code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_code). Then those object code will be linked in the link phase.

The "*Copy Bundle Resources*" copies all the resources that the app needs(assets, storyboards etc) into the bundled product.

Your library should be added in *General->Linked Frameworks and libraries*. This will automatically add your library into the *Link Binary With Libraries* phase.

Regarding the `xcdatamodel`, it needs to be added to the "*Compile Sources*" phase.